# “A Few years ago” VS “A few years before”

Tags: past-tense, adverbs

In conservations,when people talk about their past. They convey like this:

“A few years ago”, I moved in here with my family,or I moved in here with my family “ a few years before”. Do they convey the same meaning? What difference does “ago” and “before” make?

Answer (score 2):

- "A few years *ago*" means a few years before **now**. That is, the time at which you are speaking.
- "A few years *before*" means a few years before any point in time that you have previously mentioned.

For example:

> I left school at 16. A few years before I had decided I would not go to college.

That would mean the decision was made a few years prior to being 16.